# How to get Pine script syntax highlighting in Atom

Tags: atom-editor, pine-script

I want to work on script outside of trading view. Is there any plugins I can use to make coding in Atom more enjoyably for Pine script.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about Pine Script for TradingView in Atom, but there's an XML library for Notepad++.

Not as robust as Atom, but it's still a lot better than trying to code in TV directly.

Here's link to the XML:
https://www.tradingview.com/script/pDbCgvx9-4K-Notepad-UDL-Add-on-for-Pine-Script-v4-0/

PineCoders also provides a list of other tools besides Notepad++
https://www.pinecoders.com/resources/#color-pickers-or-tools